# How to use gradient in border in CSS3?

Tags: html, css, gradient

[image]

I want the above result, cant use the image because the height of the div is not fixed.

Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: To add gradient in the border of div using CSS, please refer this [link](https://css-tricks.com/examples/GradientBorder/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `pseudo classes` & `gredient background` to creating this. check updated snippet below ...

```css
.msgBox {
  padding: 3px;
  background: #f9db31;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f9db31 0%, #ff0000 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#f9db31 0%, #ff0000 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#f9db31 0%, #ff0000 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(#f9db31 0%, #ff0000 100%);
  float: left;
  margin: 50px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.msgBox::before {
  border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
  border-right: 30px solid #f9db31;
  border-top: 0 solid transparent;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  left: -27px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}
.msgBox::after {
  border-bottom: 28px solid transparent;
  border-right: 28px solid #fff;
  border-top: 0 solid transparent;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  left: -21px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 27px;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}
.innerBox {
  width: 400px;
  min-height: 200px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="msgBox">
<div class="innerBox">

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`SVG` can be used to create such shapes. It offers simplicity and scale-ability.

> However in case your case as you need flexible `height` element, may
>   be it doesn't fit your needs. I'm leaving my answer here for a possible alternate for some similar situations where it might be handy.

We can use `SVG`'s `path` element to create a shape like above and stroke / fill it with some solid color, gradient or a pattern.

Only one attribute `d` is used to define shapes in path element. This attribute itself contains a number of short commands and few parameters that are necessary for those commands to work.

Following code will create the above shape:

```
<path d="M0,25 L25,30 V20
         Q25,5 40,5 L460,5
         Q475,5 475,20 L475,170
         Q475,185 460,185 L40,185
         Q25,185 25,170 L25,50 Z" />
```

Below is a brief description of `path` commands used in above code:

- `M` command is used to define the starting point. It appears at the beginning and specify the point from where drawing should start.
- `L` and `V` commands are used to draw straight lines.
- `Q` command is used to draw curves.
- `Z` command is used to close current path. It draws a straight line from current point to the starting point to close the shape.

**Output Image:**

[image: Image with gradient border]

**Working Example:**

```css
body {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="200" viewBox="0 0 500 200">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad" x2="0" y2="1">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="yellow" />
      <stop offset="0.5" stop-color="orange" />
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="red" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <path d="M0,25 L25,30 V20
           Q25,5 40,5 L460,5
           Q475,5 475,20 L475,170
           Q475,185 460,185 L40,185
           Q25,185 25,170 L25,50 Z" stroke="url(#grad)" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />
</svg>
```

**Useful Resources:**

Below are some useful links for `SVG`:

- [Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/)
- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial)

Comment: Can I use it as a background??

Comment: @BhuwanBhatt Yes, why not. This [link](https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/) might be helpful for you.

Comment: How I will manage the height of the svg, as my div height is not fixed.

Comment: @BhuwanBhatt hmm, I see there is a limitation for this variant. I'll try to look for a possible fix.